# Function equivalent to SUM() for multiplication in SQL Reporting

Tags: ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions, reporting-services, multiplication

I'm looking for a function or solution to the following:

For the chart in SQL Reporting i need to multiply values from a Column A. For summation i would use `=SUM(COLUMN_A)` for the chart. But what can i use for multiplication - i was not able to find a solution so far?

Currently i am calculating the value of the stacked column as following:

```
=ROUND(SUM(Fields!Value_Is.Value)/SUM(Fields!StartValue.Value),3)
```

Instead of SUM i need something to multiply the values. 
Something like that:

```
=ROUND(MULTIPLY(Fields!Value_Is.Value)/MULTIPLY(Fields!StartValue.Value),3)
```

**EDIT #1**

Okay tried to get this thing running.
The expression for the chart looks like this:

```
=Exp(Sum(Log(IIf(Fields!Menge_Ist.Value = 0, 10^-306, Fields!Menge_Ist.Value)))) / Exp(Sum(Log(IIf(Fields!Startmenge.Value = 0, 10^-306, Fields!Startmenge.Value))))
```

If i calculate my 'needs' manually i have to get the following result:

[image: Needed result]

In my SQL Report i get the following result:

[image]

To make it easier, these are the raw values:

[image]

and you have the possibility to group the chart by CW, CQ or CY
(The values from the first pictures are aggregated Sum values from the raw values by FertStufe)

**EDIT #2**

Tried your expression, which results in this:
[image]

Just to make it clear:

The values in the column

```
=Value_IS / Start_Value
```

in the first picture are multiplied against each other

*0,9947 x 1,0000 x 0,59401 = 0,58573*

**Diffusion Calenderweek 44 Sums**

Startvalue: 1900,00 Value Is: 1890,00 == yield:0,99474

**Waffer unbestrahlt Calenderweek 44 Sums**

Startvalue: 620,00 Value Is: 620,00 == yield 1,0000

**Pellet Calenderweek 44 Sums**

Startvalue: 271,00 Value Is: 160,00 == yield 0,59041

---

yield Diffusion x yield Wafer x yield Pellet = needed Value in chart = 0,58730

**EDIT #3**
The raw values look like this:
[image]

The chart ist grouped - like in the image - on these fields
CY (Calendar year), CM (Calendar month), CW (Calendar week)

You can download the data as xls here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0yrzo3330adgem/2013-01-17_data.xls

The expression i use (copy / past from the edit window)

```
=Exp(Sum(Log(Fields!Menge_Ist.Value / Fields!Startmenge.Value)))
```

I've exported the whole report result to excel, you can get it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uogdh9ac2onuqh6/2013-01-17_report.xls

Comment: I just ran the command and got the value you wanted. Can you post the exact expression you are using and your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's actually a workaround. But I am pretty sure is the only solution for this infamous problem :D

This is how I did:

`Exp(∑(Log(X)))`, so what you should do is:

```
Exp(Sum(Log(Fields!YourField.Value)))
```

Who said math was worth nothing? =D

**EDIT:**

Corrected the formula.

By the way, it's **tested**.

**Addressing Ian's concern:**

```
Exp(Sum(Log(IIf(Fields!YourField.Value = 0, 10^-306, Fields!YourField.Value))))
```

The idea is change 0 with a very small number. Just an idea.

**EDIT:**

Based on your updated question this is what you should do:

```
Exp(Sum(Log(Fields!Value_IS.Value / Fields!Start_Value.Value)))
```

I just tested the above code and got the result you hoped for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the formula has to like like this?:

=Exp(Sum(Log(Fields!Value_Is.Value))) / Exp(Sum(Log(Fields!StartValue.Value)))

Comment: This is the definitely the correct answer. There can be potential issues if the values are <= 0; just something to be aware of if the data has negative values. If this is the situation you could consider the approach suggested at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx, but I've never had to use this and just use the approach above.

Comment: @DanielW. yes, but check my updated answer to address Ian's point if it could be your case.

Comment: @IanPreston check my updated answer. I think it can be a solution since the number gets close to zero (lim)

Comment: @DanielW. I just tested the updated code and worked, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @DanielW. Maybe the problem you're are getting is because of a wrong type data? Try this with all fields and see if it works CDbl(Fields!YourField.Value)

Comment: @DanielW. I'll create a test environment and see if I have the same problem. Will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @eestein Thank you, and don't stress your self. This report is driving me crazy :(

Comment: @eestein to support you i've uploaded the report code behind markup. you can get it here: [Dropbox report markup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fxbj46kcfulyd0/2013-01-18_report.xml)

Comment: @DanielW. Ok, I actually can't access dropbox from here, but I'm creating a report with your example data.

Comment: @eestein No problem, i uploaded it to my webspace, you can find it here: http://www.dwosch.net/stackoverflow/2013-01-18_report.zip

Comment: @eestein ...and here the data in an excel file http://www.dwosch.net/stackoverflow/2013-01-18_result.zip

Comment: @DanielW. Daniel, I tried with your example data and got the result you wanted, 0,58... open your SSMS and run this SQL query: `select exp(log(cast(1890 as float) / cast(1900 as float)) 
  + log(cast(620 as float) / cast(620 as float))
  + log(cast(160 as float) / cast(271 as float))
)` you should have the same result. And this is what the report is doing. Create a test yourself with only your example data and see if it still not working. Maybe the problem lays with your real data.

Comment: @eestein - Thanks, i'll try that out on monday when im back at the office. I'll get bet too u and thanks so far for your help!

Comment: @eestein Okay, when i using this one: `select exp(log(cast(1890 as float) / cast(1900 as float)) + log(cast(620 as float) / cast(620 as float)) + log(cast(160 as float) / cast(271 as float)) )` than its working - but we have entered the values hardly into the expression. But i need a dynamic expression because you have always other values. So if i change the expression to: `=SUM(EXP(LOG(CDbl(Fields!Menge_Ist.Value)))) / SUM(EXP(LOG(CDbl(Fields!Startmenge.Value))))` to be more dynamic - it does not work!

Comment: @DanielW. I know that, the static query was just an example. Have you set the data type at your dataset? When you create a dataset and define the fields you need to put in parenthesis the data type (Integer), (Boolean), etc. If it's not set you get a string, that's why I asked you to use the CDbl function. But you should check that. And another thing, have you tried to create a report with only your example data? I think you should do that to reduce the places to look into.

Comment: @eestein - Yes i have set the datatype directly in the query (for example `CAST(SUM(r.Menge_Ist) AS FLOAT) AS Menge_Ist`).  Reducing data is no problem, i can parametrize the report in the way that i get only the necessary data. I think the problem is that `=SUM(EXP(LOG(CDbl(Fields!Menge_Ist.Value)))) / SUM(EXP(LOG(CDbl(Fields!Startmenge.Value))))` is not equal to `select exp(log(cast(1890 as float) / cast(1900 as float)) + log(cast(620 as float) / cast(620 as float)) + log(cast(160 as float) / cast(271 as float)) )` in the way of execution order.. but i dont know how i can change tat

Comment: @DanielW. Your code is different then the one I provided. You are creating separate sums and then dividing. Your expression should be like this: `=SUM(EXP(LOG(CDbl(Fields!Menge_Ist.Value) / CDbl(Fields!Startmenge.Value))))`

Comment: @eestein Sorry for the late response. Was kinda busy. So i've tried and tried your solution but i was not able to get / calculate the values i needed. At the end i made the whole calculation in the sql statement. I wanted to avoid this first because of the maintainability of the statement.

Comment: @DanielW. I agree with you, but either way I honestly think there might be something wrong with your environment since it worked in my tests. Anyway, glad it worked. Cheers.