# SSRS 2008 RunningValue Multiplication

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions, multiplication

Is it possible to calculate rolling throughput yields in SSRS with RunningValue function? If not, is there another way to?

Currently I am using the expression for the orange line series:

```
=(RunningValue(((Sum(Fields!StartQty.Value) - Sum(Fields!LossQty.Value)) / Sum(Fields!StartQty.Value)), SUM, "DataSet1"))
```

And getting this expected outcome because of the SUM aggregate in RunningValue:
[image: SSRS Chart Example]

I need to get it to display 0.88, 0.62, 0.62 all the way to the end of every step unless it ran into another low first pass yield in a step.

So the calculation should be, 0.88 * 0.71 = 0.62

If it hit another bad yield on a step, 0.62 * 0.92 = 0.57 to the end.

The closest thing I could find was another question similar here on Stack Overflow but could not figure out a way to implement it in my case: [Function equivalent to SUM() for multiplication in SQL Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374470/function-equivalent-to-sum-for-multiplication-in-sql-reporting)

**Edit 1**

I forgot you cannot have nested aggregates in SSRS 2008, so I would be interested to see if there is a solution for both SSRS 2008 and 2012+

**Edit 2**

As requested in a comment, a sample data set:

[image: Sample Data]

The simple expression to calculate the blue bars is the following:

```
=((Sum(Fields!QtyStart.Value) - Sum(Fields!ScrappedQty.Value)) / Sum(Fields!QtyStart.Value))
```

Comment: I think it can be achieved using custom code, add sample data  in order to recreate your issue.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - Added an edit of the data set I am using (the graph picture is now outdated because I added a scrap to Step 5 which should now show 0.75% [not formatted to 75.00% yet])

Comment: In your sample you want to show a line with 0,88, 0.62, 0.62, 0,62... 0,62 will change only when the multiplication produces a number less than 0.62. Am I ok?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - Correct, so it will be 0.88, 0.62 until it hits step 5, which would be 0.62 * 0.75 = 0.47, then 0.47 to the end. So yes what you said is correct, until it's a number less than 0.62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated your scenario with some simpler data. For this requeriment you can use custom code to get each value by step.

Go to `Report` menu / `Report properties...` / `Code` tab. In the box use this VB code:

```
Dim prev As Double = - 1.0

Public Function GetYield(ByVal current As Double) As Double

    if prev = -1.0 then
        prev=current
        return prev
    End if      
    if (current*prev) <= prev then
        prev = current*prev
    End if
    return prev

End Function
```

Now add an additional expression to the Chart Values.

```
=Code.GetYield(
  (Sum(Fields!QtyStart.Value) - Sum(Fields!ScrappedQty.Value)) / Sum(Fields!QtyStart.Value)
)
```

In order to this works you can only call the `GetYield` function once per report, since it changes the variable `prev` per call and its value is shared across the report at runtime.

Also note prev variable is initialized with `-1` to determine the first time the function is called so if eventually the expression we are passing to the function produces -1, it will return unexpected values. Set the initial value to something you know won't be produced.

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Wow! I had no clue that custom code could use fields/properties outside of the written function and retain it's value. I feel dumb for not trying that. This is exactly what I asked for, thanks alejandro! Guess you learn things every day as they say.